# Html.EditFor passing in a new value MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Ive been looking around trying to figure this out but have had no luck.

What I want to do is pass the UserId of the person that is logged in, which I already have in UserID from my model. I have the code below and need to pass in UserID instead of last_update_by_IN.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.last_update_by_IN, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.last_update_by_IN)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.last_update_by_IN)
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.last_update_by_IN, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.last_update_by_IN)
        </div>
    </div>
```

but that was displaying the correct UserID but passing 0 to the database. Let me know if I need to clarify things more. Thanks

here is the post in my controller, forgot to add this sorry

```
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="column names here")] User_Accounts user_accounts)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(user_accounts).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.user_type_id_IN = new SelectList(db.User_Type, "userId", "userType", user_accounts.user_type_id_IN);
        ViewBag.userId = new SelectList(db.Userinfo, "userId", "pinId", user_accounts.user_id_IN);
        return View("Edit", user_accounts);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean _but passing 0 to the database_? If the .value is (say) "10", it will post back "10". Show your POST method.

Comment: Edited and added my controller code

Comment: Best guess is that you have not included the property name in the `[Bind(Include="..")]`. By default all properties are included, so if that's what you wan't, then just delete the attribute.

Comment: okay so delete the last_updated_by and add the UserID one?

Comment: If you don't include a control, then a value won't be posted back and it will be the default (i.e. assuming its `int` then the value will be `0`). Since it looks to be a value you don't want to be edited, a hidden input seems more appropriate i.e. `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserID)`

Comment: Okay but then how do I get it to change the last_updated_by field in the database to the UserID. Sorry im really new to MVC and this has me confused.

Comment: Before you save the value, `user_accounts.last_update_by_IN = user_accounts.UserID`. But its clear your not going about this the right way. If you know the value of UserID on the server, then don't render any controls for `last_update_by_IN` or `UserID`. They should only be set when you post back.

Comment: Yeah I know im not going about it the right way, hence the asking lol. Ill take what you have said and mess around with it for a bit and see if I cant figure it out. Thanks for the help.